# Context Timestamp in DataStream created by Window operation

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Let us say I have a inputStream and I perform some window operation on it. 
What is the timestamp for the event created by performing some window operation on it.

```
....
DataStream<Integer> inputStream = // ...
DataStream<Integer> countStream = inputStream.keyBy(0)
    .timeWindow(time.Seconds(1))
    .sum();
DataStream<Integer> maxStream = inputStream.keyBy(0)
    .timeWindow(time.Seconds(1))
    .max();
```

Now I want to combine the streams countStream and maxStream to find all timestamps at which the countStream for the last second was equal to the maxStream.

NOTE:
This is not exactly the problem I am trying to solve, but this is a representative example. Solving this would help me solve the real problem I need to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that the timewindows are event time windows, the events they emit will be timestamped as having occurred at the end of the window. In the case of processing time windows, the events won't have timestamps and the CPU time-of-day clock will be used as the source of timing information.

Update:

Time windows in Flink are aligned to the epoch -- they are not relative to the first event, or anything like that. You are guaranteed that two event time windows that have the same duration and offset, e.g., two one-second-long tumbling windows, will collect events for exactly the same interval of time.

The event stream emitted by an event time window is itself a stream with event time timestamps, and can be further windowed just like any other timestamped event stream. Just keep in mind that all of the events produced by one window instance (i.e., for the same second) will have the same timestamp. So if you follow a 1 sec window with a shorter window, e.g., 100 msec, then 9 times out of 10 the shorter window won't see any events.

Comment: If I am using event time, then when I have two input streams and I timeWindow for let's say 1 second (as above), do I have any guarantee that the intervals used for both the streams are identical?

i.e. For countStream if there a window interval [start_time, end_time] then is it necessary to have the same interval for maxStream. 

If that is not the case, then how can I combine the two streams?

Answer (score 0):

- For event-time-based tumbling windows which interval is 1 second. Let's see there is a window ranges in *[start_ts, end_ts)*, and it would emit results with timestamp *end_ts - 1* (that is to say *start_ts - 999* cause *end_ts* equals to *start_ts + 1000* here).
- For process-time-based senoraios, no timestamp info. generated.

Update:

If you want elements from the same upstream window to end up in the same downstream window. You may use [Consecutive windowed operation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#consecutive-windowed-operations).

Steps:

1. combine your *countStream* with *maxStream* by `union`.
2. window the combined streams with `windowAll`.
3. do your business logic in some `process` function following `windowAll`.